# I want to add delay between image tags. How can i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout, delay

My project : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Suicideus/Lwneabv2/3/)

```
setTimeout(function() {


for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {


    $('.rastgele').append('<img class="g59" src="https://cdn.intgrl.co/G59/static/images/window.png">');


}



$('.g59').each(function(index) {

    $(this).css({
        left: ((Math.random() * $('body').width())),
        top: ((Math.random() * $('body').height())),

    });

});


/*$('.g59').delay(5000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).show();
    next();
});*/

}, 2000);
```

But it doesn't work. I want to like https://g59records.com/ I want half second between each img tag. I added delay,i used setTimeout or setInterval but it doesn't work for me. What can i do guys? Please help me.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It's not going to work because your `for` loop is iterating 15 times inside your `setTimeout`. Use a `setInterval` and remove the `for` loop - you only need the `.append()` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of setTimeout you need to use setInterval to call it again and again.

```
var imagesOnWindow=20;
var i=1;
var start
start = setInterval(function() {
        var left=((Math.random() * $('body').width()));
        var top=((Math.random() * $('body').height()));
        var _img=$("<img/>",{
            class:"g59",
            src:"https://cdn.intgrl.co/G59/static/images/window.png",
        });
        $(_img).css('top', top);
        $(_img).css('left', left);
        console.log(_img);
        $('.rastgele').append(_img);
        i++;
        if(i>imagesOnWindow)
          clearInterval(start);
        }, 1000);
```

you can see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/Lwneabv2/15/)

Comment: @Suicideus can you please accept and upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for `for` loop, you can do with set Interval and stop interval when counter reach 15.

```js
var counter = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {

    if (counter > 15) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return false;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://cdn.intgrl.co/G59/static/images/window.png";
    img.className = "g59";
    $('.rastgele').append(img);
    $(img).css({
        left: ((Math.random() * $('body').width())),
        top: ((Math.random() * $('body').height())),

    });
    counter++;

}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rastgele"></div>
```

Comment: @Suicideus If you got this  answer useful then accept this answer by clicking on right tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        (
         function(i) {setTimeout(function() {
            var left = Math.random() * $('body').width();
            var top = Math.random() * $('body').height();
            $('.rastgele').append('<img class="g59" style="left:'+left+'px;top:'+top+'px;" src="https://cdn.intgrl.co/G59/static/images/window.png">');

          }, 500*i)
   })(i);  

}
```